# Find docs where field value does not exists in other docs using ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a problem retrieving all the docs, that do not have corresponding other logs by field value. I would appreciate any help given. The easiest to explain is with an example:

I have the following 5 docs:

DOC1:

```
{
     message: **Step1**,
     id: 100
}
```

DOC2:

```
{
     message: **Step2**,
     id: 100
}
```

DOC3:

```
{
     message: **Step1**,
     id: 200
}
```

DOC4:

```
{
     message: **Step2**,
     id: 300
}
```

DOC5:

```
{
     message: **StepX**,
     id: 400
}
```

So what I would like as a response from a query, would be all the docs, where Step1 does not have the corresponding Step2, where id value is the same. In the example below, this is (**RESPONSE I WANT)**:
DOC3:

```
{
     message: Step1,
     id: 200
}
```

What I tried so far is not the result I would like. This returns count of docs by id and ascending order, but since we have many other Steps, this is not ok, and results with count 1 will not be always correct.

```
GET index/_search
{
      "size": 0, 
      "aggs" : {
          "langs" : {
              "terms" : { 
                    "field" : "id",  
                    "size" : 10, 
                    "order": {
                      "_count": "asc"
                     }
               }
          }
     } 
}
```

**MORE DETAILS**
In response, I need docs, that does **not** have 2 docs related with one id field (each result should have only 1 doc with related id and message=Step1).

Comment: Which field(message/id) value?

Comment: @Suresh For the result, I would need all the docs, where "Step2" value is missing on "message" field with "id" field of value "x" -> in above example this is 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "x"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "message"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be ok if I would have those ids (x in this example). I want this dynamic. It means that I will get docs for each id, that does not have the corresponding message. And btw, field "message" must always exist. I need docs, that does not have 2 docs related with one id field (one with message=Step1, another with message=Step2)